# Carrying SmartFoxServer connection across Android Activities

Tags: android

I am using SmartFoxServer for a multiplayer game.  I have it working fine when it loads up in the main chat room.  In my app you an create new game rooms and when you click on one it launches a new activity and enters that room.  It appears I have to connect to the server again after that.  Then I get already logged in error.

How can I maintain the smartfox client throughout my activities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the Application class and make your server reference a static public variable which will be available from any Activity using `((YourApplication)getApplication()).yourStaticServerReference`.

To override your Application class, follow the following steps :

- Create a class extending Application, let's call it `com.yourpackage.YourApplication`

  ```
  package com.yourpackage;


  import android.app.Application;


  public class YourApplication extends Application {
      public static SmartFoxServer smartFoxServer;


      @Override
      public void onCreate() {
          smartFoxServer = initSmartFoxServer(); // I don't know SmartFoxServer's API so let's imagine you implement this somewhere in the Application class.
          // Now the smartFoxServer field is like a global variable visible in all your Activities using ((YourApplication)getApplication()).smartFoxServer
      }
  }
  ```
- In your application manifest you have to edit the application declaration :

  ```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:name="com.yourpackage.YourApplication">
  ```

If you often access the smartFoxServer object, you can even use java 1.5 static import feature :

```
import static com.yourpackage.YourApplication.smartFoxServer;

public Activity myActivity {
    public void anyMethod() {
        // Thanks to the static import, smartFoxServer is directly accessible, without calling getActivity().
        smartFoxServer.doSomething();
    }
}
```

I wrote this directly here so there might be some things wrong... I will check this in more details when the kids let me more than 2 minutes of free time ;-)

Comment: I have read another solution like that.  Currently my app uses two different tab activities.  Where would I extend that application class at?

Comment: I quickly updated my answer with more details... so quickly that I might have missed something so I'll go back and check later if evrything is ok.

Comment: Thanks a ton.  I implemented this and it looks like it is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for helping me to understand the whole application extension concept

Comment: Glad to help, so please check your question as answered ;-)